# git commit --amend not recognizing valid vimrc options

Tags: vim, vimrc

This is the error I am getting, when I do `git commit --amend`

```
Error detected while processing /root/.vimrc:
line  193:
E518: Unknown option: foldmethod=indent
line  194:
E518: Unknown option: foldlevel=99
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I know this is not related to `git`, but vim is working alright otherwise.

This is the vimrc I am using: https://github.com/sontek/dotfiles

Comment: What is Vim's version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

probably the same issue as

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870884/vim-says-no-mouse-support-but-only-when-i-run-git-commit

which recommends

git config --global core.editor vim